# Physical HDD emulation

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I own an standalone DVR system (used for video surveillance) which apparently has an embedded Linux inside of it...
The DVR writes the recordings on a locally attached SATA HDD.

Because I have no possibility to configure that embedded Linux to write the data to a NAS, I need to find some physical/hardware component to emulate a locally attached SATA HDD (as if a HDD were connected locally, but on the other side transmit the data over the LAN to my NAS like an iSCSI initiator...)

Does anyone know any hardware component for such a job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The closest industry solution to your problem would be something like ATA-over-Ethernet. However this is almost certainly a far more expensive solution than you'd like to consider (prices all-in from $400 USD min).

Perhaps if you elaborate why you want to achieve this a more specific suggestion could be made, but I expect your best bet will be to replace the DVR with one which would let you use a NAS for storage.

Comment: I've been also thinking about this. I guess you're right :) Thanks!